# Are there any negative effects if user logged in twice?

Tags: firebase-authentication

i have the following method

```
FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: emailController.text), password: passwordController.text);
```

**Producing the wording of the question in steps**

1- user called the previous method , and he logged in successfully

2- user repeated the same first step (Although he was logged in successfully)

I performed the previous steps and did not notice any strange behavior, But I want to make sure that there are no effects

Sometimes I want to do this operation for some reasons .

Comment: "*Sometimes I want to do this operation for some reasons.*" What are your reasons?  You can certainly check to see if the user is already signed in before trying to sign them in again.  This would avoid any sort of problems you might be worried about.

Comment: the following method FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.updatePassword(newPasswordController.text) gives an error expectation called error.code = 'requires-recent-login' and this error code happening when user change his password two times at the same session , so the soliton was is to call signIn method in the top of the updatePassword method and user can change it anytime at the same session .. so that was my reason to call it twice

Comment: Did you see the documentation on [how to reauthenticate the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#re-authenticate_a_user)?

Comment: thanks, your comment solved my problem instead of calling  signIn method for twice , but i am a bit confused , in link your shared they says  'it happen because user signed in too long ago' , well, can i use signIn  method  instead of reauthenticate method ? i mean does it will do the same job of reauthenticate method ?